# hyperledger composer modelling language knowhow

Tags: composer-php, modeling, hyperledger

I am new to blockchain. Anybody have any document on hyperledger composer modelling language. I do not know how to write it? Thanks

Comment: You can follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48423204/5167909

Answer (score 0):

Specifically on the data model language:
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/cto_language.html

But frankly, you have a lot of reading to do overall, so take a look at the links at the top left corner. Start with tutorials and then browse the docs ... enjoy!